# Make Fragment as app bundle entry point in android app

Tags: android, app-bundle

Hi I just wanted to know if we separate one bundle from main module of app and that module entry point is a fragment instead of Activity, then will it work ? Because I tried with fragment it throws resource not found exception on inflating layout in onCreateView while it is present in R file. Also it worked in debug mode properly. Has anyone tried till now ??? If yes, please let me know.

Comment: Bro not getting, Can you please elaborate your problem with screens if possible.

Comment: @ArjunG I separated one module of my project as another bundle, and entry point of that module is a fragment. And when I tried to load that module on demand it gets crashed as explained in the question. while for activity it works fine.

Comment: Without activity you can't probably show a fragment. You must be having a container activity for the fragment. You should use that instead

Comment: @VivekMishra I have the activity but that is in base module not in sub-module.

Comment: Check import of R file into fragment. There are many open questions. Where you getting exception... for layout or for views inside layout... where is stacktrace.. there is a conflict which is causing this issue, you need to resolve taht. And what do you mean of it is running into debug mode?

Comment: @PankajKumar while I directly run on device it works because all code present at once and as I told the layout for which it throws exception Resource not found, it is present in R file of that module. Yes I checked open questions, it's not that much direct issue. So I asked here.

Comment: try it on viewCreated();